# Set payment method with admin access token with rest api

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I want to set the payment method on behalf of the customer, with the admin access token.
I don't have the customer access token but I have the customerId
I used this API call: carts/{cartId}/payment-information it throw an error:
{
"message": "Request does not match any route."
}

Comment: check if you are using POST method. if you use other than POST you will get "Request does not match any route." error

Comment: Yes it's with the POST method